ZeroMQ (C++): sending pointer with inproc
I am trying out ZeroMQ (zmq) for the multithreaded program.
I want to avoid copying the data that need to be passed to workers.
My idea was to send the pointer to the data as a zmq message.
It works. But I discovered that if I change the data inside the worker, the producer (main) does not see it. I wonder why!
Here is an example:
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <zmq.h>

struct Foo {
  explicit Foo(int value) noexcept
  : _value{value}
   {}
  int _value;
};

void worker(void *context)
{
  void *receiver = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REP);
  zmq_connect(receiver, "inproc://example");

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));

  zmq_msg_t message;
  zmq_msg_init(&message);
  zmq_msg_recv(&message, receiver, 0);

  char received[sizeof(Foo *)];
  std::memcpy(&received, zmq_msg_data(&message), sizeof(Foo *));

  //reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(received)->_value = 111;
  std::cout << "Received Foo with value: " << reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(received)->_value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "   the address of value: " << std::addressof(reinterpret_cast<Foo *>(received)->_value) << std::endl;

  zmq_msg_close(&message);
  zmq_close(receiver);
}

int main()
{
  void *context = zmq_ctx_new();
  void *sender = zmq_socket(context, ZMQ_REQ);
  zmq_bind(sender, "inproc://example");

  std::jthread thread{worker, context};

  auto foo{ std::make_unique<Foo>(42) };

  std::cout << "Sending Foo with value : " << foo->_value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "   the address of value: " << std::addressof(foo->_value) << std::endl;

  zmq_msg_t message;
  zmq_msg_init_size(&message, sizeof(Foo *));
  std::memcpy(zmq_msg_data(&message), foo.get(), sizeof(Foo *));
  zmq_msg_send(&message, sender, 0);

  zmq_msg_close(&message);
  zmq_close(sender);
  zmq_ctx_destroy(context);

  return 0;
}

The output I get is
Sending Foo with value : 42
   the address of value: 0x55a8c6fe2a90
Received Foo with value: 42
   the address of value: 0x7f30c0a52d40

As you can see, the addresses of _value are different, so that explains why changing the value inside the worker does not affect the producer. But I don't understand why they are different.
Lastly, is this even the right approach to send data without copying it via inproc transport?


Q2 :" (...) is this even the right approach to send data without copying it via inproc transport? "

Well, within the ZeroMQ Zen-of-Zero, which includes a warranty of receiving either a binary-exact copy of original, or nothing at all ( a warranty of content consistence, not delivery ),yes.
The rest is in your design. The inproc transport is known as the fastest ( Zero-copy, memory-pointing ), minimum overhead, transport available inside ZeroMQ toolbox.

Q1 :" I wonder why! (?) "

Your "outer" code has no clue, that you not only move the pointers, but also generate ( outside the "sight" of heavily optimising compiler ) change(s) of the underlying ( weakly only ref'd ) value.
Not surprised the collisions appear, as compiler had no clue from the source code this will ever happen "behind" it's back.
May try to inspect and compare how differently the compiler handles ( yes, read actual assembly instructions used ) common variable declarations versus a volatile ear-marked designated variables, to get some ideas, what defense strategies are available not to let the "originator" rely on ( not adequate here ) optimising compiler "assumptions".
Reference documentation is often quite clear on these "surprises", like this :

21.2 volatile Variables and Fields
The GNU C compiler often performs optimizations that eliminate the need to write or read a variable.(...)If the memory containing foo is shared with another program, or if it is examined asynchronously by hardware, such optimizations could confuse the communication. Using volatile is one way to prevent them.
Writing volatile with the type in a variable or field declaration says that the value may be examined or changed for reasons outside the control of the program at any moment. Therefore, the program must execute in a careful way to assure correct interaction with those accesses, whenever they may occur.

